# Windows Universal Apps: storing configuration

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

i come from web development where apps can have multiple config files for storing things like db connection strings, remote server endpoints, passwords and so on

so you have files like base.config, development.config, production.config, local.config and so on

according to the environment the app is running in the correct config file is loaded

is there any such system for Windows Phone and Windows Store apps?

if so, how can i define different configs for diffrent runtimes such as debug and production?

i would really like to avoid storing runtime config in code and then using crazy ifs

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in system for this, but it's pretty easy to mock up. Create and read a file with your config information then create different files for the different configurations. Create a pre-build step which copies the appropriate file for the desired configuration.

I'd probably name the files all the same but put them in different directories named for the $(Configuration) then copy from the $(Configuration) dir in my pre-build.

See [Pre-build Event/Post-build Event Command Line Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx) on MSDN

There isn't an easy way to switch this at runtime since you can't write to the appx package after it's signed and deployed.

Comment: ok, kinda complicated. so this is the best practice then? what kind of file format would you suggest? xml? or is there anything simpler?

Comment: Up to you. XML's pretty easy. You could also use JSON. Both have in-box serialization support.